# Can a cursor hold variables in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql

I know that a cursor can encapsulate a query, but can it also point to a variable value or multiple ones?

For example:

```
declare
my cursor refcursor;
var_x varchar;
begin
        var_x := (select x from table where id = 7);
        open mycursor for select(var_x);
end;
```

Is this possible in PL/pgSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it can be done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_value_cursor(_curs refcursor, _id1 int, _id2 int)
  RETURNS TABLE (col1 int, col2 text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
    var_x text := (SELECT t.col2 FROM tbl t WHERE t.tbl_id = _id1);
BEGIN

OPEN _curs FOR SELECT var_x;

RETURN QUERY
SELECT t.col1, t.col2
FROM   tbl t
WHERE  t.tbl_id >= _id2;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

A cursor is good for *any* query that returns rows - even if it returns a single constant like in the example.

Using an unbound cursor variable as parameter, you can pass a name for the cursor to the function.

I made the function return a table at the same time, since that seems to be what you are after in those last couple of questions.

As mentioned [in my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23115413/issue-when-migrating-stored-procedure-from-sql-server-to-postgresql), it is essential that you fetch values from the cursor in the *same transaction*:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM f_value_cursor('mycursor', 1, 2);
FETCH ALL FROM mycursor;
ROLLBACK; -- or COMMIT
```

[**SQL Fiddle**.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/12dc3/1)

For the record: consider a [**temporary table**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785767/postgresql-table-variable/10790059#10790059) instead, which lives for the duration of the session (per default), not just for the transaction. Tables are much more versatile. Cursors make more sense for huge result sets.